# Euler Equation in General Relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity

For a perfect fluid the stress-energy tensor is $T^{\mu \nu} = (\rho + p)u^{\mu}u^{\nu} + pg^{\mu \nu}$, thus the equations of motion read:

$$0 = T^{\mu \nu}_{\; \; \; ;\nu}  =  (\rho + p)_{;\nu}u^{\mu}u^{\nu} + (\rho + p)(u^{\mu}_{\; ;\nu}u^{\nu} + u^{\mu}u^{\nu}_{\; ;\nu} ) + p_{;\nu}g^{\mu \nu}$$

Now I want to project this equation using $P_{\alpha \mu} = u_{\alpha} u_{\mu} + g_{\alpha \mu}$. According to the book's calculations the following term: $$P_{\alpha \mu}(\rho + p)_{;\nu}u^{\mu}u^{\nu}$$ vanishes and I don't understand why.

How does this term vanish?

Comment: I think it's simply because $P_{\alpha \mu}u^{\mu} = -u_{\alpha} + u_{\alpha} = 0$ by construction. See for example Eckart: [*The thermodynamics of irreversible processes. III. Relativistic theory of the simple fluid*](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.58.919) or Gourgoulhon: [*3+1 Formalism in General Relativity: Bases of Numerical Relativity*](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0703035).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just, to make it more clear (as mentioned in the comment), first prove this

$${P_{\alpha \mu }}{u^\mu } = ({u_\alpha }{u_\mu } + {g_{\alpha \mu }}){u^\mu } = {u_\alpha }\underbrace {{u_\mu }{u^\mu }}_{ =  - 1} + \underbrace {{g_{\alpha \mu }}{u^\mu }}_{ = {u_\alpha }} = 0,$$

and hence, you get this

$${P_{\alpha \mu}}(\rho + P){  _{;\nu }}{u^\mu }{u^\nu } =\underbrace{{P_{\alpha \mu }}{u^\mu }}_{ = 0}(\rho + P){_{; \nu }}{u^\nu } = 0.$$